# How to ensure that the text paragraphs on the right side are consistent in the formula environment in the Latex?

Tags: latex, xelatex

I try to write the following formula in Latex
[image]

My question is that how to write the right-hand side formula? How to ensure that the text paragraphs on the right side are consistent in the formula environment?

My code is

`$\mathbb{P}[\mbox{there exists a black path from ${0}\times [0,s]$ to $\pho s\mtis [0,s]$ in the rectangle $0,\pho s]\times [0,s]$}]`

Comment: Can you make a [mre] and clarify what exactly you mean with "[...] are consistent in the formula environment"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Text

\[
f_s(\rho)=\mathrm{P}%
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
\text{there exists a black path from }\{0\}\times [0,s]\text{ to}\\
\{\rho s\}\times [0,s]\text{ in the rectangle }[0,\rho s]\times [0,s]
\end{array}
\right].
\]

Text
\end{document}
```

giving this output:

[image: screenshot of output pdf]

Comment if this is ok with your code or not! `:)`